# On the properties of an interesting set on the real line...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $K$ be the set of all real numbers of the decimal form
$$
0.\;e_1\;\underbrace{0}_{1!\text{ times}}\;e_2\;\underbrace{00}_{2!\text{ times}}\;e_3\;\underbrace{000000}_{3!\text{ times}}\;e_4\;\underbrace{00\dots00}_{4!\text{ times}}\;e_5\;\underbrace{00\dots00}_{5!\text{ times}}\dots\\
$$
where $e_i\in\{1,2\}$.

I found this set when I was trying to find a counter-example for the following statement

"Every uncountable set $A\subseteq\mathbb R$, has a rational limit point."

Obviously **$K$ is uncountable**. Now let $L$ denote the set of all Liouville numbers, then we can easily prove that $K\subset L$. But we know that the set $L$ is null and every element of $L$ is transcendental, hence **$K$ is a null set and every element of $K$ is transcendental**.
I proved that **$K$ is a perfect set**, i.e. $K'=K$, hence **$K$ is a Baire space**.
This set has many interesting properties but I just tried to write those with higher importance...for example every element of $K$ has unique decimal representation. You may find many interesting properties of this set.

> I want to make this set interesting for others by showing that $K$ is a nice counter-example for many famous problems in mathematics. Thanks in advance...

Comment: "every element of $K$ has a unique decimal representation" is hardly an interesting property. The other properties you mention are of some interest, but you will have to find some really fabulous properties of your set to merit any further discussion. Also, the fact that your set depends on a decimal expansions diminishes its quality.

Comment: Yes...you're right. But the set has many properties like Cantor set.

Comment: @k1.M: Your set is _a_ Cantor set, in the topological sense that it is the image of the usual middle-thirds Cantor set under a homeomorphism $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Maybe.....If you're right, then the set has it's topological properties like the Cantor set, but what about arithmetic properties? I'm not interested only about it's topological or cardinality properties...so I'm not sure to call it as a Cantor set.

Comment: Observe that at first I found it  a counter-example for an arithmetic statement....